# Default value for input type file in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an input type file to upload an image. I want to also set one default image for it such that if user doesn't upload any the defaut gets saved/used. How can this be done?

```
Template.modelMeta.events({
    'submit #uploader-form': function(e, t)
    {



    file = $('#desc-model-thumb') // id for input type = file

    var fsFile = new FS.File(e.target[2].files[0]);


    ThumbFiles.insert(fsFile,function(err,thumbFile) {
        if (err) {
        sAlert.error("No image or invalid image format selected", {effect: 'flip', onRouteClose: false, stack: false, timeout: 8000, position: 'top'});
        } else {
        sAlert.success("Image has been Uploaded", {effect: 'flip', onRouteClose: false, stack: false, timeout: 4000, position: 'top'});     
        ModelFiles.update(modelId, {$set: {name: filename, about: description, thumbnail:thumbFile._id}}, function(error, res) {
            if (error) {
            sAlert.error(error.reason);
            } else {
            sAlert.success("Data about model has been saved", {effect: 'flip', onRouteClose: false, stack: false, timeout: 4000, position: 'top'});
            }
        });

        }
    }); 
    } 
});
```

This is a template

```
    <label for="filename" class ="input-head"> Model-Image </label>
    <p class ="help-text"> An image that will be used as a thumbnail for your model, the preferred size is 500 X 300 </p>   
    <input class="form-control model-thumb" id="desc-model-thumb" name="modelThumb" type="file">
```

Collection

```
ThumbFiles = new FS.Collection ("thumbFiles", {
    stores: [
    new FS.Store.FileSystem("thumbFiles")
    ],
    filter: {
    allow: {
        contentTypes: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg']
        // extensions: ['jpg']
    }
    }   
});
```

Comment: Can you add a little more detail to the question? How would you know if the user had uploaded an image already (is a link stored in her profile)?

Comment: I have updated my post. Please check

Comment: Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just link up a default file if the user didn't define one:

```
defaultSAlert = {
  effect: 'flip',
  onRouteClose: false,
  stack: false,
  timeout: 8000,
  position: 'top'
}

function insertImage (fsFile, modelId, description) {
  ThumbFiles.insert(fsFile,function(err,thumbFile) {
    if (err) {
      return sAlert.error("No image or invalid image format selected", defaultSAlert);
    }
    sAlert.success("Image has been Uploaded", defaultSAlert);
    updateModelFiles({
      _id: modelId,
      thumbnail: thumbFile._id,
      name: thumbFile.original.name,
      description: description
    })
  });
}

function updateModelFiles (model) {
  ModelFiles.update(modelId,
    {
      $set: {
        name: filename,
        about: description,
        thumbnail: fileId
      }
    }, function(error, res) {
      if (error) {
        return sAlert.error(error.reason);
      }
      sAlert.success("Data about model has been saved", defaultSAlert);
    }
  );
}

Template.modelMeta.events({
  'submit #uploader-form': function(e, t) {
    file = $('#desc-model-thumb') // id for input type = file
    if(file.files.length) {
      insertImage(
        new FS.File(file.files[0]),
        undefined,
        undefined
      )
    } else {
      var defaultModel = ModelFiles.findOne({ $eq:{name: 'defualt.png'} })
      defaultModel._id = undefined
      updateModelFiles(defaultModel)
    }
  }
});
```

Notice in my call to the `insertImage` function i used `undefined` twice. That's because I don't know what the `description` an `modelId` should be. Also, I'd try and properly indent your stuff. It barely readable the way you posted your code. And use **2 spaces** for indentation. It's the convention.

Comment: Ok, I will take care next time and thanks a lot. But after doing this the page gets refereshed and no default and even no image gets uploaded.

Comment: Sorry, there still were some errors I hadn't caught before. I fixed them. And did you replace the `undefined`s in your code?

Comment: Yes, I replaced them :(

Comment: You can see my edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31055850/2). And a diff of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31055850/revisions)